# is there a notification counterpart for application:performFetch WithCompletionHandler?

Tags: ios, multitasking

When the background fetching feature turned on, iOS will wake up app(by calling the "application:performFetch WithCompletionHandler" in Appdelegate) to fetch data so when user launch the app, he will see the refreshed contents.

is there a system notification for "application:performFetch WithCompletionHandler" ?

Comment: What do you mean by "notification counterpart"? Do you mean if you can receive a notification every time background fetch is about to happen or if you can send a notification when background fetch is happening?